# How to Count multiple records with specific type

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to filter different records based on its category type

I have two table as 
product and product_detail

product

```
   p_id    p_name    p_cat_id
    1      computer1    101
    1      computer2    101
    2      mobile1      102
    2      mobile2      102
    2      mobile3      102
```

product_detail

```
   cat_id  cat_name  cat_staus
    101    computer     active
    102    mobile       active
    103    electronics  active
```

I want to count following records based on category type
such as computer1 and computer2 with cat_id so output will be computer = 2

query:

```
SELECT product_id,cat_name, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT product_detail.cat_name) AS "my_product" 
        FROM product 
        INNER JOIN product_detail ON product.p_id = product_detail.cat_id
GROUP BY product_detail.cat_id
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: i want count based on category

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e try `GROUP BY product_id, cat_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of products that have a certain type of category; that is: "For each category, show the name of that category and the number of products with that category"

In that case, use this:

```
SELECT cat_name,
        COUNT(1) AS amount 
        FROM product
        INNER JOIN product_detail ON product.p_id = product_detail.cat_id
GROUP BY product_detail.cat_id
```

The INNER JOIN will already create a list of all products in a category. The GROUP BY will let you see each category specifically. All you need is the COUNT of rows for each category.

Comment: @Shareque just one small note: `COUNT(1)` not equal to `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`. You need to know what exactly is your goal.

Comment: the 1 is just the number 1, which is return for every row. The Count function is used to count a number of rows. It doesn't really matter what you use as input for the count function in this case; using 1 is a sort of convention. (Try "SELECT 1 FROM product" to see what I mean)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product.p_cat_id,
       product_detail.cat_name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT product.p_name) AS "my_product_count" 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN product_detail 
ON product.p_cat_id = product_detail.cat_id
GROUP BY product.p_cat_id
```

Answer (score 1):

query:

```
SELECT product_detail.cat_name,
        COUNT(p_cat_id) AS "my_product" 
        FROM product 
        INNER JOIN product_detail ON product.p_cat_id = product_detail.cat_id
GROUP BY  product_detail.cat_name
```